# How to pass data to the canActivate service guard?

Tags: angular

There is routes definition :

```
{ path:'some_path', component: some_component, canActivate: some_service}
```

How to pass data to the some_service ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can pass it this way:

first in your route definition add data property:

```
{ path:'some_path', component: some_component, canActivate: some_service, data: {routeData: <what ever you want to pass>}}
```

then in your some service guard you can access the data:

```
canActivate( route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot ): Observable<boolean> {

    let routeData = route.data.routeData;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all You should add a service implement CanActivate Interface:

```
import { CanActivate, Router, ActivatedRouteSnapshot } from "@angular/router";
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
@Injectable()
export class MyCustomRouteActivator implements CanActivate {
  constructor(private router: Router) {
    //You could inject a service has your currentUserData . . .  
  }
  canActivate(router: ActivatedRouteSnapshot) {
    //You could get data from router service like params //id username ....
    let canVisitPage = false;// add your conditional function here;
    if (!canVisitPage) {
      this.router.navigate([/404]);/ / choose your custom page path
}
  }
}
```

Then add this service to your app.module.ts :

```
providers:[....... MyCustomRouteActivator]
```

Finally You could use it on your route now:

```
//import MyCustomRouteActivator
{ path:'some_path', component: some_component, canActivate: [MyCustomRouteActivator]}
```

Comment: you did not specify how to pass data

Comment: Sorry for my time. It's a basic knowledge that's why I haven't write it. Silly me....